# Simplify The If and else IF Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
ALTER PROCEDURE spDisplayTableNames1
    @T_ID INT OUT,
    @BatchNumber VARCHAR(30) OUT
AS
BEGIN
    IF((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblPacks 
        WHERE T_ID = @T_ID 
          AND BatchNumber = @BatchNumber) = 0) 
    AND ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblBlisters 
          WHERE T_ID = @T_ID 
            AND BatchNumber = @BatchNumber) = 0) 
    AND ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblShippers 
          WHERE T_ID = @T_ID AND BatchNumber = @BatchNumber) = 0)
BEGIN 
    PRINT '0 0 0'
END
ELSE IF((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblPacks WHERE T_ID=@T_ID AND BatchNumber=@BatchNumber)>0) AND ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblBlisters WHERE T_ID=@T_ID AND BatchNumber=@BatchNumber)=0) AND ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblShippers WHERE T_ID=@T_ID AND BatchNumber=@BatchNumber)=0)
BEGIN
Print '1 0 0'
END
ELSE IF((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblPacks WHERE T_ID=@T_ID AND BatchNumber=@BatchNumber)=0) AND ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblBlisters WHERE T_ID=@T_ID AND BatchNumber=@BatchNumber)>0) AND ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblShippers WHERE T_ID=@T_ID AND BatchNumber=@BatchNumber)=0)
BEGIN
Print '0 1 0'
END
ELSE IF((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblPacks WHERE T_ID=@T_ID AND BatchNumber=@BatchNumber)=0) AND ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblBlisters WHERE T_ID=@T_ID AND BatchNumber=@BatchNumber)=0) AND ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblShippers WHERE T_ID=@T_ID AND BatchNumber=@BatchNumber)>0)
BEGIN
Print '0 0 1'
END
ELSE IF((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblPacks WHERE T_ID=@T_ID AND BatchNumber=@BatchNumber)>0) AND ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblBlisters WHERE T_ID=@T_ID AND BatchNumber=@BatchNumber)>0) AND ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblShippers WHERE T_ID=@T_ID AND BatchNumber=@BatchNumber)=0)
BEGIN
Print '1 1 0'
END
ELSE IF((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblPacks WHERE T_ID=@T_ID AND BatchNumber=@BatchNumber)>0) AND ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblBlisters WHERE T_ID=@T_ID AND BatchNumber=@BatchNumber)=0) AND ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblShippers WHERE T_ID=@T_ID AND BatchNumber=@BatchNumber)>0)
BEGIN
Print '1 0 1'
END
ELSE IF((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblPacks WHERE T_ID=@T_ID AND BatchNumber=@BatchNumber)=0) AND ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblBlisters WHERE T_ID=@T_ID AND BatchNumber=@BatchNumber)>0) AND ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblShippers WHERE T_ID=@T_ID AND BatchNumber=@BatchNumber)>0)
BEGIN
Print '0 1 1'
END
ELSE IF((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblPacks WHERE T_ID=@T_ID AND BatchNumber=@BatchNumber)>0) AND ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblBlisters WHERE T_ID=@T_ID AND BatchNumber=@BatchNumber)>0) AND ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblShippers WHERE T_ID=@T_ID AND BatchNumber=@BatchNumber)>0)
BEGIN
Print '1 1 1'
END

END
```

Here I am checking conditions on three tables and if a column exists in three tables it should print '1 1 1', if it exists only in first and third table then print '1 0 1'. Like that I wrote 8 conditional statements. But I want a simplified query for the above stored procedure

I want the simplest query for the above example - how can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
declare @prt varchar(10);
if ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblPacks WHERE T_ID=@T_ID AND BatchNumber=@BatchNumber)=0)
    set @prt = '0';
else
    set @prt = '1';

if ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblBlisters WHERE T_ID=@T_ID AND BatchNumber=@BatchNumber)=0)
    set @prt = @prt + ' 0';
else
    set @prt = @prt + ' 1';

if ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblShippers WHERE T_ID=@T_ID AND BatchNumber=@BatchNumber)=0) 
    set @prt = @prt + ' 0';
else
    set @prt = @prt + ' 1'; 

print @prt;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
DECLARE @PRINT VARCHAR(10)=''

SELECT @PRINT = @PRINT+CAST(PR AS VARCHAR(10))+' ' FROM (
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT 1) AS PR FROM tblPacks WHERE T_ID=@T_ID AND BatchNumber=@BatchNumber
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT 1) FROM tblBlisters WHERE  T_ID=@T_ID AND BatchNumber=@BatchNumber
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT 1) FROM tblShippers WHERE  T_ID=@T_ID AND BatchNumber=@BatchNumber
)A

SELECT @PRINT
```

If the record exist in a table then the `COUNT(DISTINCT 1)` will give One `1`  ,otherwise Zero(`0`).

Next store the result set in a variable by appending every record into it.

Comment: I think this would give an extra space at the beginning, for example ' 1 0 0' instead of '1 0 0'. But that's probably easily fixed ...

Comment: No. It won't give Space as prefix. But space will come in the last. If we need we can remove. However the Trailing spaces not a matter

Comment: You're right, it's a trailing space, I misread the code. Either is easily fixed by LTRIM() or RTRIM() ...

Answer (score 2):

I am answering because `if (select count(*) . . .)` is a very bad idiom.  This requires running an aggregation query to see if a single row exists.  A better approach is `if exists()`.

In addition, all the conditional logic can be done in a `select`:

```
declare @prt varchar(10);

select @prt = (case when exists (select 1 from tblpacks where T_ID = @T_ID  and BatchNumber = @BatchNumber)
                    then '0' else '1'
               end) +
              (case when exists (select 1 from tblBlisters where T_ID = @T_ID and BatchNumber = @BatchNumber)
                    then ' 0'
                    else ' 1'
               end) +
              (case when exists (select 1 from tblShippers where T_ID = @T_ID and BatchNumber = @BatchNumber)
                    then ' 0';
                    else ' 1'
               end)
              )
print @prt;
```